# Create date pairs from list of dates in one column table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem with a SQL query. I have a list of dates in one column, I would like to create pairs of dates. The dates are sequenced, so I have to match the first date with the second and create a record, then the third date with the fourth date and create a record etc .. as in the following example:

```
ID  DATA
50  10/04/2019
50  12/04/2019
50  13/04/2019
50  17/04/2019
50  18/04/2019
50  19/04/2019

ID  DATA_START  DATA_END
50  10/04/2019  12/04/2019
50  13/04/2019  17/04/2019
50  18/04/2019  19/04/2019
```

Thanks very much everyone for the help

Comment: Have a look at `LEAD`/`LAG`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mark your rows that should be grouped together (into single row) and which date will have which role (start or end).

Here's the code:

> ```
> with a as (
>   /*Source data*/
>   select 50 as id, convert(date, '2019-04-10', 23) as dt union all
>   select 50 as id, convert(date, '2019-04-12', 23) as dt union all
>   select 50 as id, convert(date, '2019-04-13', 23) as dt union all
>   select 50 as id, convert(date, '2019-04-17', 23) as dt union all
>   select 50 as id, convert(date, '2019-04-18', 23) as dt union all
>   select 50 as id, convert(date, '2019-04-19', 23) as dt
> )
> select
>   id,
>   [1] as dt_start,
>   [0] as dt_end
> from (
>   select
>     id,
>     dt,
>     /*
>       the first row (with modulo = 1) is date from
>       and the second row (with modulo = 0) is date to
>     */
>     (row_number() over(partition by id order by dt)) % 2 as dt_role,
>     /*Integer division by 2 will group rows together*/
>     (row_number() over(partition by id order by dt) + 1) / 2 as dt_group
>   from a
> ) as s
> pivot (
>   max(dt) for dt_role in ([0], [1])
> ) as p
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | dt_start   | dt_end    
> -: | :--------- | :---------
> 50 | 2019-04-10 | 2019-04-12
> 50 | 2019-04-13 | 2019-04-17
> 50 | 2019-04-18 | 2019-04-19
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fb61a5b06310cedc176d98c65b41d73c)*